# Angular directive animate move a div

Tags: angularjs

I want when mouse hover on image, a description div animate from bottom to middle of image, like this [link](http://www.nintendo.com/ds) in product image when hove a div from down move to up.
i done amount of this in this plunker site [plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/due8afgmVkUUhqkDbhwE?p=preview)  i can not animate 
please help, thanks.

Comment: This in not an AngularJS related question, but rather one on CSS. Search for simple CSS3 animations. Also, consider a retag and provide your code inside of this very post, rather than linking to an external plnkr, in order to get more attention.

Comment: when you trying to `$compile` html and append it with your directive. `ngAnimate` will not be triggered. However you can use simple `:hover` + some css transition to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a look at AngularJS, I can not see the jQuery animation methods in the jQLite subset (http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element) that comes with AngularJS, so I would confer the AngularJS docs on how to include the full jQuery lib into your AngularJS project (start with http://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq).

Then use jQuery animate, see http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: I am not sure that this is a good advice, woulnd't it be a better solution to use pure CSS animation for this use case, instead of "polluting" with unnecessary usage of jQuery?

Comment: That is a valid concern. On the other hand heavy is relative, using large JS code bases in my day work, I see jQuery as a rather light lib.

Comment: thanks for answer, but i want not use Jquery and i cannot how must do this by css